# Hazelcast keySet streaming?

Tags: java, memory, java-stream, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

I'm new to Hazelcast, and I'm trying to use it to store data in a map that is too large than possible to fit on a single machine.

One of the processes that I need to implement is to go over each of the values in the map and do something with them - not accumulating or aggregation and I don't need to see all the data at once, so there is no memory concern with that.

My trivial implementation would be to use `IMap.keySet()` and then to iterate over all the keys to get each stored value in turn (and allow the value to be GCed after processing), but my concern is that there is going to be so much data in the system that even just getting the list of keys will be large enough to put undue stress on the system.

I was hoping that there was a streaming API that I can stream keys (or even full entries) in such a way that the local node will not have to cache the entire set locally - but failed to find anything that seemed relevant to me in the documentation.

I would appreciate any suggestions that you may come up with. Thanks.

Comment: does my response make sense to you?

Comment: hi Guss. do you have any questions? otherwise, please, accept my answer. Thank you

Comment: Thanks for your response, eventually it wasn't what we went with, but as the project was also scuttled, I'm not highly invested in that :-) . For future projects I'd like to look at Jet anyway and the intro you provided was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Hazelcast Jet provides distributed version of `j.u.s` and adds «streaming» capabilities to `IMap`.
It allows execution of Java Streams API on the Hazelcast cluster.

```
import com.hazelcast.jet.JetInstance;
import com.hazelcast.jet.stream.DistributedCollectors;
import com.hazelcast.jet.stream.IStreamMap;
import com.hazelcast.jet.stream.IStreamList;

import static com.hazelcast.jet.stream.DistributedCollectors.toIList;

    final IStreamMap<String, Integer> streamMap = instance1.getMap("source");
    // stream of entries, you can grab keys from it
    IStreamList<String> counts = streamMap.stream()
                    .map(entry -> entry.getKey().toLowerCase())
                    .filter(key -> key.length() >= 5)
                    .sorted()
                    // this will store the result on cluster as well
                    // so there is no data movement between client and cluster
                    .collect(toIList());
```

Please, find more info about jet [here](http://jet.hazelcast.org) and more examples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-jet-code-samples).

Cheers,
Vik

Comment: A stream of entries is even better. Questions: `.flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.getSingleVal()))` seems redundant? What do you mean when you write "so there is no data movement between client and cluster" - aren't all entries stream to the client where we're running the process?

Comment: The client will send computational task described with your `j.u.s` pipeline to we cluster. It will be executed in the cluster and result will be written to the cluster (check that `toIList` collect method)

Answer (score 0):

While the Hazelcast Jet stream implementation looks impressive, I didn't have a lot of time to invest in looking at upgrading to Hazelcast Jet (in our pretty much bog-standard vert.x setup). Instead I used `IMap.executeOnEntries` which seems to be doing about the same thing as detailed for Hazelcast Jet by @Vik Gamov, except with a more annoying syntax.

My example:

```
myMap.executeOnEntries(new EntryProcessor<String,MyEntity>(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Override
    public Object process(Entry<String, MyEntity> entry) {
        entry.getValue().fondle();
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public EntryBackupProcessor<String, MyEntity> getBackupProcessor() {
        return null;
    }});
```

As you can see, the syntax is quite annoying:

1. We need to create an actual object, that can be serialized to the cluster - no fancy lambdas here (don't use my serial ID, if you copy&paste this - its broken by design).
2. One reason it cannot be lambda is that the interface is not functional - you need another method to handle backup copies (or at least to declare that you don't want to handle them, as I do), which while I acknolwedge its importance, its not important all of the time and I would guess that its only important in rare cases.
3. Obviously you can't (or at least its not trivial) to return data from the process - which is not important in my case, but still.